# kivy: plot and screen manager; plot not showing up

Tags: python, kivy

I am not sure wheter my probplem with kivy and graph is related to [this issue](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/7), or if I did something wrong. Here is my min

The main file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from math import sin

"""
Activate the touch keyboard. It is important that this part is on top
because the global config should be initiated first.
"""
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'multi')

from kivy.app import App
# The Builder is used to define the main interface.
from kivy.lang import Builder
# use the screen manager to switch between screens
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as rgb


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class DataScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DataScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        graph_theme = {'label_options': {'color': rgb('595959'), 'bold': False},
                       'background_color': rgb('DBE49A'),
                       'tick_color': rgb('999999'),
                       'border_color': rgb('808080')}

        self.graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
                      x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
                      y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
                      x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1,
                           **graph_theme)
        self.add_widget(self.graph)

    def plot_data(self):
        plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 1, 0, 1])
        plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
        self.graph.add_plot(plot)


class MyApp(App):
    """
    The settings App is the main app of the pHBot application.
    It is initiated by kivy and contains the functions defining the main interface.
    """


    def build(self):
        """
        This function initializes the app interface and has to be called "build(self)".
        It returns the user interface defined by the Builder.
        """
        Builder.load_file('phapp.kv')
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen())
        sm.add_widget(DataScreen())
        # returns the user interface defined by the Builder
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The kivy file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: 'Go to data'
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.root.current = 'data'
        Button:
            text: 'Exit'
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.stop()

<DataScreen>:
    name: 'data'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Graph:
            size_hint_y: 0.9
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
            text: 'Start plotting data'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: root.plot_data()
        Button:
            size_hint: (1, 0.1)
            text: 'Back to main menu'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: app.root.current = 'main'
```

Any ideas why my plot does not show up ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mostafar at Github asked this same question, and thanks to @tshirtman, the [following answer](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/7#issuecomment-41507644) was provided:

> After a chat with @tshirtman, He found out the problem is with
>   stencilbuffer and by changing line 139 of **init**.py of graph module
>   to:
>
> ```
> self._fbo = Fbo(size=self.size, with_stencilbuffer=False)
> ```
>
> It will be visible in my example, but then there will be many problems
>   with new features of graph (SmoothLinePlot).

Link: https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.graph/issues/7